deriving formulas for pentagon area and dodecahedron volume
Does anyone know how the regular pentagon area formula A = ${\tfrac{1}{4}}\sqrt{5(5+2\sqrt{5})}\thinspace s^2$ and the regular dodecahedron volume formula V = $\frac{15+7\sqrt{5}}{4}s^3$ are derived?  Visuals are appreciated if they don't take too much time or effort to find or make.

For the area of a regular pentagon, it is useful to know $\sin\left(\frac \pi 5\right) =\frac{\sqrt{10-2 \sqrt{5}}}{4}$, which you can deduce from trigonometric sums

To calculate the dodecahedron volume formula, I'd start by looking at the pentagonal pyramid with base one of the faces and peak at the center of the dodecahedron. It'll help to know that there's a dodecahedron with side length $\frac{2}{\phi}$ with vertices at $(\pm 1,\pm 1,\pm 1), (\pm \phi, \pm 1/\phi, 0)$ ($\pm$ signs are independent) and all cyclic permutations thereof. There's a good image at https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Dodecahedron_vertices.svg

^I derived it that way and have the formulas, which include trig.  I'm just curious how the  above formulas were derived.  I think the latter involves breaking up the dodecahedron into different-shaped and -sized pieces but I'm not sure.

You said you derived it and then you said you are curious how they are derived. What exactly do you want answer for?

^I want to know how the above formulas are derived.  I derived different formulas that use trig functions.

@John: "I derived different formulas that use trig functions." Please provide the derivations you have, so that people don't waste time duplicating your effort, explaining things you already understand, or giving approaches that aren't "different" enough. (It's no fun conceiving, composing, formatting, and illustrating a comprehensive answer only to have the asker respond, "Yeah, that's how I did it. I want something else.") Include this information in the body of the question; comments are easily overlooked and may be hidden.

@John: Also, note that ^ doesn't work here, since comments are often presented out of order due to up-voting. To indicate the target of a reply-comment, @-name them (as I did with you here); this will also ensure they see a notification of the comment.

Area of the pentagon
Consider a regular pentagon with side-length $s$:

First, consider the following angles:

Notice that $5{\color{green}\beta}=2\pi$, $2{\color{blue}\gamma}+{\color{green}\beta}=\pi$, and ${\color{red}\alpha}=2{\color{blue}\gamma}$, which implies that
$$({\color{red}\alpha},{\color{green}\beta},{\color{blue}\gamma})=\left(\frac{3\pi}{5},\frac{2\pi}{5},\frac{3\pi}{10}\right)$$
If you only consider a small right triangle (whose area is a tenth of the area of the pentagon)

and using the formula
$$\tan(\theta)=\frac{\text{opposite}}{\text{adjacent}}$$
you obtain an equation on its height $h$:
$$\tan({\color{blue}\gamma})=\frac{h}{s/2}$$
hence
$$h=\frac{s\tan({\color{blue}\gamma})}{2}=\frac{s}{2}\tan\left(\frac{3\pi}{10}\right)$$
The area of the grey triangle is
$$\mathrm{A}_{\triangle}=\frac{\text{base}\times \text{height}}{2}=\frac{sh}{4}=\frac{s^2}{8}\tan\left(\frac{3\pi}{10}\right)$$
So the area of the pentagon is
$$\mathrm{A}=10\mathrm{A}_{\triangle}=\frac{5s^2}{4}\tan\left(\frac{3\pi}{10}\right)$$
The last step is to find an explicit value for $\tan({\color{blue}\gamma})$:
$$\tan({\color{blue}\gamma})=\sqrt{\tan({\color{blue}\gamma})^2}=\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos(2{\color{blue}\gamma})^2}{(\cos(2{\color{blue}\gamma})+1)^2}}$$
Consider $z=\exp(3i \pi /5)$, so that $\cos(2{\color{blue}\gamma})=\mathfrak{Re}(z)$. The following computation are adapted from the very good answer of Jakobian to this question. We know that $z^5=e^{3i \pi}=-1$, hence
$$0=z^5+1=(z+1)(z^4-z^3+z^2-z+1)$$
But $z\ne -1$, and therefore $z^4-z^3+z^2-z+1=0$. $z\ne 0$ so we can multiply by $1/z^2$ on both side to get
$$0=z^2-z+1-\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{z^2}=u^2-u-1\text{ where }u=z+\frac{1}{z}$$
We can easily solve for $u$ and get
$$u\in\left\{\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2},\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right\}$$
But $\cos(3\pi/5)<5$, hence the only possible answer for $u$ is
$$u=\frac{1{\color{red}-}\sqrt{5}}{2}=-\frac{1}{\varphi}=1-\varphi$$
where $\varphi$ is the golden ratio. For $z$ we get the equation
$$z+\frac{1}{z}=-\frac{1}{\varphi}\iff z^2+\frac{z}{\varphi}+1=0$$
whose discriminant is
$$\Delta=\frac{1}{\varphi^2}-4=\frac{1}{\varphi+1}-4<0$$
The solutions are therefore given by
$$z\in\left\{\frac{-1/\varphi \pm i \sqrt{-\Delta}}{2}\right\}$$
We also know that $\mathfrak{Im}(z)=\sin(3\pi/5)>0$, and we deduce that the only possible solution is
$$z=\frac{-1/\varphi {\color{red}+} i \sqrt{-\Delta}}{2}$$
Finally,
$$\cos\left(\frac{3\pi}{5}\right)=\mathfrak{Re}(z)=-\frac{1}{2\varphi}=\frac{1-\varphi}{2}$$
and
$$\tan({\color{blue}\gamma})=\sqrt{\frac{1-(1-\varphi)^2/4}{((1-\varphi)/2 +1)^2}}=\sqrt{\frac{4-(1-\varphi)^2}{(3-\varphi)^2}}=\sqrt{\frac{1+\varphi}{3-\varphi}}$$
The radicand can be computed easily:
$$\frac{1+\varphi}{3-\varphi}=\frac{1+\varphi}{3-\varphi}-1+1=\frac{2(\varphi-1)}{3-\varphi}+1=\frac{2}{3\varphi-\varphi^2}+1=\frac{2}{2\varphi-1}+1=1+\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}$$
leading to
$$\tan({\color{blue}\gamma})=\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}}$$
and
$$\boldsymbol{\mathrm{A}=s^2\frac{5}{4}\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}}=\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{5(5+2\sqrt{5})}s^2}$$

Volume of the dodecahedron
Consider a regular dodecahedron with side-length $s$, and cut-out the following cube

We obtain a partition of the solid into a cube and six tent-like prisms:

The length of the cube is a diagonal of a side $s$ pentagon, hence $a=\varphi s$. The very good answer by theyaoster on this post gives precise computations of some measurements in this prism.
(to be continued)

The images are pretty good! What software are you using?

Thank you, I use Geogebra (to construct most of the 3D shapes) that I draw them on mathcha.io to edit it and get the TikZ code!

This is awesome, thank you so much! :-)  Do you happen to know the name of the green shape?

You're welcome! This shape may be called à wedge (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wedge_(geometry))

Nice pics & work. +1 I will read completely later.

Since you want visuals, try this for the pentagon and this for the dodecahedron.

Great video for the pentagon!

In the following I have minimized figures hoping the given description encourages imagination for construction.
Regular Pentagon base
Each half-side is $AM$. Sum of 5 external angles= 360. so each external angle is 72 deg. Internal supplement angle at vertex is 108 degrees.  Half this angle is what the radius $BM$ makes  to any of the 5 sides equalling 54 degrees in the base plane $AMB$.
Draw 5 isosceles triangles  with their altitudes as in-radii $r=BM$. Look at one of these 10 half right angled triangles. Their angles are $ (54, 36, 90) $ degrees. If $ x= 18 ^{\circ} $ then abbreviating sin,cos as $s,c$
$$ \sin 36 ^{\circ}=  \cos 54 ^{\circ}\to \sin 2x = \cos 3x \to 2~s~c= 4 c^3-3c $$
$$ \text{since } c^2+s^2=1,~ \text{ this simplifies to }~4s^2 + 2s-1=0 $$
Solving
$$ \sin 18 ^{\circ}=  \frac{ \sqrt 5-1}{4}= 1/(2 \varphi); \varphi= ~\text{ GoldenRatio}; \cos 18 ^{\circ}= \frac{\sqrt{10- 2 \sqrt 5}}{4}; $$
Now use formula $ \frac12 $ Base multiplied by Height of each of 5 isosceles triangles and you get the result.
Regular Dodecahedron
Dihedral angle is $ \delta=\pi- \tan^{-1}2$ make triangle $OBM$ in vertical plane including a new hypotenuse including $ \delta/2$ between the planes as dihedral. Since there are 12 regular pentagons at base there are 120 such pyramids where three right angles with sides $(BA,BM,BO)$ come to a common vertex at any dodecahedron edge midpoint $M$.

For base triangle area is $\Delta =\frac12 . AM.BM$, altitude $h= OB $
Use formula $ \Delta\cdot h/3 $ of each pyramid volume shown above, multiply by 120 to get the full Volume.

The unit sided regular pentagon can be placed on Cartesian plane with center at the origin and two of its consequitive vertices
$$P_0=(\tfrac{\sqrt{\sqrt5}\sqrt\phi}{\sqrt5},0)$$
$$P_1=(\tfrac1{2\sqrt{\sqrt5}\sqrt\phi},\frac\phi2)$$
So its area is
$$A_0=\frac52||\vec{OP}_0\times\vec{OP}_1||=\frac{\sqrt5}2(4\phi+3).$$
where $\phi$ is the golden ratio. The area of the regular pentagon with side s is $A=A_0 s^2.$
The volume of a dodechahedron can be found similarly.
I wrote the answer. It is lost before saving. Must be a joke.
